# How do I convert 1024 KB to 1 MB with the output?

Tags: regex

I have this

```
/([^\/\|\#\<\(\>\;\s][0-9]*[\s][KB]{2})
```

in order to be specific i had to use **[KB]{2}**
I  get the value needed, but can I convert the final print to MB?

Exemple: match= 2000KB = 2MB?

Thanks

Comment: give some example input and output

Comment: Please choose tags carefully. Your question is now totally unclear because you didn't tell anything about the context you're working in. What language? Is this regex? Etc. Elaborate and tag accordingly.

Comment: `[KB]{2}` should simply be `KB`

Comment: Further to @John's comment, `[KB]{2}` will match KK and BB. `[KB]` defines a character class (ie. what characters match) containing the characters K and B, and the `{2}` specifies that that character class should match twice in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can; capture the unit and the number separately like this:

```
/[^\/\|\#\<\(\>\;\s]([0-9]*)[\s]([KB]{2})
```

Assuming your original regex is correct, of course.  Then:

```
if ($2 eq "KB" && $1 > 1024) {
    $1 /= 1024;
    $2 = "MB";
}
```

Comment: I started to learn regex expressions 2 days ago, that regex was the one that worked for me, thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: If this answers your question be sure to click the check box.

Comment: if I don't use {2} would it match KBites?

Comment: @raFF: "[KB]{2}" matches "KB" or "KK" or "BK" or "BB".  "KB" matches only "KB".

Answer (score 0):

lol on the sting `"2000 KK"` your regex matches

```
$1 = 000
$2 = KK
```

better try this one ;)

```
/(\d+)\s*(KB)/
```