# Regex match 1024KB convert to 1MB?

Tags: regex, match

I get the file size from the index of the page, it's 1024KB and I want it to print 1MB stead of 1024KB, what should I do? (completely noob here)

I got this:

```
if($row[2]==1) // Rapidshare Check
{
  $index=getpage($row[1]);
  if(strpos($index,"FILE DOWNLOAD")===false) //check if page contains the word file download  if not = bad link
  {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `v2links` SET `checked`='-1',`lastcheck`=NOW() WHERE `id`=".$row[0]);
    print "bad link\n";
    logstr("log-c.txt","bad link\n");
   }
   else
   {

    preg_match("**/([^\/\|\#\<\(\>\;\s][0-9]*[\s][KB]{2})/**",$index,$match);

     $fsize=$match[1];



  print $fsize."\n";
  logstr("log-c.txt","bad link\n");
  //logstr("log-c.txt","$caption | $fsize\n");
  mysql_query("UPDATE `v2links` SET `checked`='1',`fsize`='$fsize',`lastcheck`=NOW() WHERE `id`=".$row[0]);
  unset($match);
  }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert 1024 KB to 1 MB with the output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419031/how-do-i-convert-1024-kb-to-1-mb-with-the-output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How accurate do you want the conversion to be?

```
s/0*([0-9]+)[0-9]{3}K/\1M/g
```

will lop off the last three numbers of a four or greater digit size... but it's a truncation, and doesn't even *consider* math.  (For example, 1999K -> 1M)

A possibly better method would be to `s/K/000/g` and `s/M/000000/g` to turn it into a (crude) number of bytes, and then convert as  you want back down.

The best possible method would be to process it, if it has a M multiply by 1024*1024; if it has K multiply by 1024. (if it has G, multiply by 1024*1024*1024).  Then, process the resulting size however you're trying to.
--Note that it'd be a good plan to store file size as an integer, rather than a string.

For processing and output, a series of if's are probably good enough, and you can set precise tollerances for how big something must be to be displayed as M instead of K.
--Or if you just want M, there's no if, and you just divide by 1024*1024.

Comment: thanks, i'm not sure how to integrate the regex that you gave with the one I have! sorry..

Comment: if you could give me an example on how to process it, I'd appreciate even more! :D

thanks

Comment: For the transformations (EX: easy), replace `$fsize=$match[1];` with `$fsize=preg_replace('/0*([0-9]+)[0-9]{3}K/', '$1M', $match[1]);`.